# What is the difference between SHGO and Nevergrad optimization technique?

Tags: python, optimization, nevergrad, shgo

I am currently trying to find some use cases to differentiate between the two optimization techniques i.e. Nevergrad (PSO) and SHGO. or which is more useful.
Please help me with this..

Comment: It looks like shgo is a method implemented in scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.shgo.html), while Nevergrad is a standalone library (https://github.com/facebookresearch/nevergrad). It looks neither of them uses gradients, so they may be the same in this respect. You can test both, or specify your goals (if you already use scipy, I would recommend to use its module).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.